# Get notified when a QTextEdit get a new Undo item

Tags: qt, qtextedit, undo-redo

my widget contains lots of `QTextEdit` controls. Actually all these `QTextEdits` are installed as item widgets for a `QTreeWidget`. all these controls are editable in place.

So, I need to implement a unified "undo stack", process `control + "Z/Y"` in my widget instead  of each `QTextEdit` control. For this I have to take a record whenever a certain `QTextEdit` make a new undo item. So when I press `control+Z`, it will undo a `QTextEdit` control's editing(by invoking its undo() method), press again probably will undo another `QTextEdit` control's editing(by invoking its undo() method).

But when searched through the document,I found no such signal that notifies me that a new undo item is made for a `QTextEdit`. And I have no idea about the undo policy of a `QTextEdit`, sometime multiple keypress was compressed into one single undo item, so using a keypress eventfilter and record my own `QUndoCommand` probably not a good idea, not mentioned that `QTextEdit` provide its own convenient method undo()/redo().

How can I get arround this?

Comment: Undo redo related with multiple textedit controls. But my undo redo call may comes from the treeItem.

Comment: Sorry for not been clear enough.  What I want is when user press control+Z in my treeWidget, it will undo each QTextEdit linearly. Say I changed text in textEdit01, then changed text in textEdit02, pressing undo in treeWiget will first undo textEdit02 changement,then textEdit01.

Comment: Are you able to do a single undo in any QTextEdit right now?

Comment: It have redoAvailable signal which you can use to undo other all textedits. But I think connecting it directly to undo of others will cause a recursive call so try some trick to use this signal.

Comment: Redo/undoAvailable signal only seem only been triggered when the state changed,from no undo item to has a undoitem.  I could of course do a single undo in any single QTextEdit, the issue is I have to undo multiple QTextEdit in a linear way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `QTextDocument::undoCommandAdded` is the signal you're looking for.